# Scroll Div Left and Right on click with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have the following script to scroll a div up and down. I wanted to know if there is a way it can be amended to now go left and right. I did what seemed obvious, which was to change the ele.scrollTop to ele.scrollRight. What would be the correct amendment to the script?

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/swQ7J/5/

Original (Top/Bottom) Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    var ele   = $('#scroll');
    var speed = 25, scroll = 5, scrolling;

   $('#scroll-up').click(function() {
        // Scroll the element up
        scrolling = window.setInterval(function() {
            ele.scrollTop( ele.scrollTop() - scroll );
        }, speed);
    });

    $('#scroll-down').click(function() {
        // Scroll the element down
        scrolling = window.setInterval(function() {
            ele.scrollTop( ele.scrollTop() + scroll );
        }, speed);
    });

    $('#scroll-up, #scroll-down').bind({
        click: function(e) {
            // Prevent the default click action
            e.preventDefault();
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            if (scrolling) {
                window.clearInterval(scrolling);
                scrolling = false;
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Make a fiddle at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: Sure thing! Just added the link to the question, I'll include it here as well: http://jsfiddle.net/swQ7J/5/

Comment: There does not seem to be a need to scroll left or right since your text wraps

Comment: Perfectly, your text seems wrapped and you will have to add your implementation of scroll left/right...

Comment: I get your point, in the JS Fiddle I used text, however the real implementation consists of a grid of images/tiles that I want to be scrollable on the site. So the implementation of left/right should only consist of changing ele.scrollTop to ele.scrollLeft?